# linux command line question

Tags: linux, command-line

If I have a program that takes a number of files, specified on the command line as input:

```
myprog file1 file2 file3
```

and a text file containing the names of those files, one per line, is there a way to run the line above but using only the text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as simple as using:

```
myprog $(cat file-name)
```

And file-name is

```
cat file-name
file1
file2
file3
```

Comment: In sufficiently recent `bash` and `zsh` this can be shortened to `myprog $(<file-name)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Assuming that the text file contains each file name on its own line, you can run:

```
cat names-of-those-files.txt | xargs my-program-that-takes-files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myprog `cat filelist.txt`
```

Cool... you don't even need to convert `\n` to space.